# Mocking object that are generated dynamically + rspec-mock

Tags: rspec-rails, rspec-mocks

I am using jruby(9.1.12.0) with rspec-rails(3.7.0).

I have the following method

```
class AddressCreator
  include Singleton
  attr_reader :client

  def initialize
    @client = SomeJavaClass.new(some keys go here)       
  end
end

# SomeJavaClass has an create_address instance method.

def create_address(user_id, address)
  req = Java::RandomRequest.new(user_id, address)
  resp = Java::RandomResponse.new(default_response_params)
  AddressCreator.instance.client.create_address(some_key, req, resp)
end
```

And have added the tests for the same as

```
describe '#create_address' do
  let(:some_key) { SecureRandom.uuid }
  let(:user_id) { 1 }
  let(:default_response_params) { false }
  let(:address) { 'some address goes here' }
  let(:request) { Java::RandomRequest.new(address)}
  let(:response) { Java::RandomResponse.new(default_response_params)}

  before {allow(AddressCreator.instance.client).to receive(:create_address).with(some_key, request, response).and_return(response)}

  it 'should create the address' do
    result = AddressCreator.instance.client.create_address some_key
    expect(AddressCreator.singleton).to have_received(:create_address).with(some_key, request, response) do |request|
      expect(request.is_success).to eq(response.is_success)
    end
    expect(result).to eq(response)
  end
end
```

My specs fail stating

```
expected  <Java::RandomRequest:0x1d09fb8e>
got       <Java::RandomRequest:0x38482732>
```

How do we mock so that we received the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of the `Java::RandomRequest` and `Java::RandomResponse` that you create in spec do not match those that you create in `create_address`.
Try stubbing the classes to return the values you need like:

```
let(:request) { instance_double(Java::RandomRequest) }
let(:response) { instance_double(Java::RandomResponse) }
before do
  allow(Java::RandomRequest).to receive(:new).and_return(request)
  allow(Java::RandomResponse).to receive(:new).and_return(response)
end
```

Also, you can collapse `allow` in `before` with `expect... have_received` after `create_address` call to a spy called before the `create_address` action, e.g.:

```
# no before block
it 'should create the address' do
expect(AddressCreator.singleton)
  .to receive(:create_address)
  .with(some_key, request, response) do |request|
    expect(request.is_success).to eq(response.is_success)
  end
  result = AddressCreator.instance.client.create_address some_key
  expect(result).to eq(response)
end
```

Another option would be to use [`kind_of`](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.4/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers.html#kind_of-instance_method)/[`instance_of`](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.4/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers.html#instance_of-instance_method)/[`duck_type`](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.4/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers.html#duck_type-instance_method) argument matchers instead of stubs if you don't intend to check how exactly request and response are initialized, e.g. something like:

```
# no before
it 'should create the address' do
  expect(AddressCreator.singleton).to receive(:create_address)
  .with(kind_of(String), instance_of(Java::RandomRequest), duck_type(:is_success)) do |request|
    expect(request.is_success).to be_true
  end
  AddressCreator.instance.client.create_address some_key
end
```

Lastly, you don't have to initialize `some_key` with real secure key, double would be enough if you don't process and just pass to some stubbed class in the end:

`let(:some_key) { double }`